# Tried to open AIT file, but blank empty canvas showed up instead. Help?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-format, template, error

I'm trying to open an AIT file through both the "open" and "file >> new with template" options, but only a blank empty canvas shows up.

I also tried creating a new file and then placing the ait file in the canvas, but then it says "the document contains PDF objects that have been reinterpreted" and when I go on it pastes in a file that's just a bunch of repeated text saying "This is an Adobe Illustrator file that has been saved without PDF content."

I would link to the file I'm not sure how to do that on stackexchange...

Note: I did not create the AIT file, I'm just trying to edit it.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to open a newer template in an older version of AI.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open or edit an AIT file directly.  It's a template file that has to be applied when opening a new document.

To get around this, you could open a new document based on a template, then afterwards save that new document as a new template.

Please check the [documentation from Adobe on the use of AIT files](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/files-templates.html):

> Create a new document from a template
>
> 1) Do one of the following:
>
> - Choose File > New From Template.
> - Choose File > New. In the New Document dialog box, click Templates.
> - In the Welcome screen, click From Template in the Create New list.
>
> 2)  In the New From Template dialog box, locate and select a template,
>   and click New.

Please also note that many of the templates installed with Illustrator are in fact nothing more than blank documents, set up for you to use.

Comment: Hmm I tried your suggestion, still nothing shows up

Comment: @MelanieSanders - see the extra note I added to the answer.  Many of Illustrator's templates installed with the software are nothing but blank documents.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that lol. But I'm not using any of the default templates, but one made by my instructor. when they showed the template in class, I saw that there were visible elements in it, containers and lines and stuff...

Comment: Thank you though!

Comment: If the containers are empty and lines have no stroke, you might need to select all to see them.

Comment: I tried that too and emailed the instructor. Nothing so far :(